# Elementary question on wedging 2-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Consider two smooth manifolds $M_1, M_2$ with symplectic forms $\omega_1, \omega_2$. The following excerpt is from Cannas da Silva, Lectures on *Symplectic Geometry*:

[image]

Concerning the last line. For notational convenience, write $\omega = \theta + \eta$. For $n=1$, we get
$$
\omega^2 = (\theta + \eta) \wedge (\theta + \eta) = \theta^2 + 2 (\theta \wedge \eta) + \eta^2,
$$
since $\theta \wedge \eta = \eta \wedge \theta$. But what happens with the $\eta^2$ and $\theta^2$, why do they vanish?
Similarly, one finds, if I am not mistaken, for $n = 2$,
$$
\omega^{4} = \theta^4 + 4 \theta^3 \wedge \eta + 6(\theta^2 \wedge \eta^2) + 4 \eta^3 \wedge \theta + \eta^4.
$$
(The resemblance with the binomial formula is obvious. But again, the middle term is what we need to get, but what happens with others?)

Comment: The others are $0$, since a $k$-form on an $n$-manifold is $0$ automatically when $k>n$

Comment: Aren't all summands of top degree? For $n=1$, the manifold is of dimension 4, and the degree of $\theta^2$, $\theta \wedge \eta$ and $\eta^2$ is all 2+2.

Comment: In $\sum_{j=1}^k \binom{k}{j} \eta^j\wedge \theta^{k-j}$, with $k<n$, there is no reason for any term to vanish. But for $k=2n$, it only remains $\binom{2n}{n} \eta^n\wedge \theta^n$, since any other term has $\eta^{n+1}$ or $\theta^{n+1}$ as a factor, which is zero

Comment: Presumably, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are $n$-dimensional manifolds!

Comment: Right. As Didier commented, you were too vague about dimensions when you started off. Keep track carefully of which term has which degree. Regarding your first comment (after mine), $\theta^2$ is a $4$-form on $M_1$, which is a $2$-manifold.

Comment: You're right. I should have stated more explicitely what dimensions are involved. But since we are considering $\omega^{2n}$ it should be clear that $M_1, M_2$ are $2n$-dimensional (and hence, $M_1 \times M_2$ is $4n$-dimensional) as $\omega^{2n}$ is supposed to be the volume form on $M_1 \times M_2$. (Recall that a $2$-covector $\alpha$ on some $2m$-dimensional vector space $V$ is symplectic if $\omega^{m} \neq 0$.) So this resolves the 1st issue. The 2nd, I am pointing to is that $\theta$ is a pullback of $\text{pr}_1: M_1 \times M_2 \to M_1$, so  $\theta^2 \in \Omega^4(M_1 \times M_2)$, no?

Comment: But $\theta^2$ is the pullback of the square of a form on $M_1$, and that makes it the pullback of $0$.